# How to fix (android.database.CursorWindowAllocationException) crash

Tags: android, sqlite, parse-platform

Before the Local Datastore feature in Parse was available, I used to have my own local database for offline app usage. I think everything worked well until I decided to add a homescreen widget to my app, with its service and a listview that was fed from that local DB. After a while I started to get some errors from users(Cursor Allocation, # Opened Cursors), I thought it was something minor, maybe due to phone issues,etc,  but then I myself started experiencing them...I tried to tackle them in every possible manner suggested in SO, various types of solutions, trying to close everything pointing to the DB, try/catch stuff, etc, nothing. So after some months, I gave up and said to myself, that's it, going to use the Local DataStore from Parse, which I'm sure it's better than my sqlite implementation.

This was maybe a month ago,and I thought things were solved, but today got this error, that appears even without the app being used. I stopped the apps and services, reboot/power off, but it is still there just when the phone unlocks and since this afternoon can't open the app because of it, it is constant.

I don't know how to fix it, it's been a 4 months nightmare. Hoping for a helping hand, thanks.

```
07-21 19:01:29.360: E/CursorWindow(17106): Could not allocate CursorWindow '/data/data/com.xoaquin.r07d/databases/ParseOfflineStore' of size 2097152 due to error -12.
07-21 19:01:29.470: E/CursorWindow(17106): Could not allocate CursorWindow '/data/data/com.xoaquin.r07d/databases/ParseOfflineStore' of size 2097152 due to error -12.
07-21 19:01:29.480: E/AndroidRuntime(17106): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-21 19:01:29.480: E/AndroidRuntime(17106): Process: com.xoaquin.r07d, PID: 17106
07-21 19:01:29.480: E/AndroidRuntime(17106): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.xoaquin.r07d.DefaultApplication: android.database.CursorWindowAllocationException: Cursor window allocation of 2048 kb failed. # Open Cursors=582 (# cursors opened by this proc=582)
07-21 19:01:29.480: E/AndroidRuntime(17106):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4471)
07-21 19:01:29.480: E/AndroidRuntime(17106):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:145)
07-21 19:01:29.480: E/AndroidRuntime(17106):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1266)
07-21 19:01:29.480: E/AndroidRuntime(17106):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-21 19:01:29.480: E/AndroidRuntime(17106):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-21 19:01:29.480: E/AndroidRuntime(17106):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5141)
07-21 19:01:29.480: E/AndroidRuntime(17106):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-21 19:01:29.480: E/AndroidRuntime(17106):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-21 19:01:29.480: E/AndroidRuntime(17106):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
07-21 19:01:29.480: E/AndroidRuntime(17106):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:611)
07-21 19:01:29.480: E/AndroidRuntime(17106):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-21 19:01:29.480: E/AndroidRuntime(17106): Caused by: android.database.CursorWindowAllocationException: Cursor window allocation of 2048 kb failed. # Open Cursors=582 (# cursors opened by this proc=582)
07-21 19:01:29.480: E/AndroidRuntime(17106):    at android.database.CursorWindow.<init>(CursorWindow.java:104)
07-21 19:01:29.480: E/AndroidRuntime(17106):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.clearOrCreateWindow(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:198)
07-21 19:01:29.480: E/AndroidRuntime(17106):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:139)
07-21 19:01:29.480: E/AndroidRuntime(17106):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:133)
07-21 19:01:29.480: E/AndroidRuntime(17106):    at com.parse.ParseSQLiteDatabase$12.then(ParseSQLiteDatabase.java:214)
07-21 19:01:29.480: E/AndroidRuntime(17106):    at com.parse.ParseSQLiteDatabase$12.then(ParseSQLiteDatabase.java:205)
07-21 19:01:29.480: E/AndroidRuntime(17106):    at com.parse.Task$11.run(Task.java:481)
07-21 19:01:29.480: E/AndroidRuntime(17106):    at com.parse.Task$ImmediateExecutor.execute(Task.java:673)
07-21 19:01:29.480: E/AndroidRuntime(17106):    at com.parse.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:477)
07-21 19:01:29.480: E/AndroidRuntime(17106):    at com.parse.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:353)
07-21 19:01:29.480: E/AndroidRuntime(17106):    at com.parse.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:364)
07-21 19:01:29.480: E/AndroidRuntime(17106):    at com.parse.Task$9.then(Task.java:410)
07-21 19:01:29.480: E/AndroidRuntime(17106):    at com.parse.Task$9.then(Task.java:402)
07-21 19:01:29.480: E/AndroidRuntime(17106):    at com.parse.Task$11.run(Task.java:481)
07-21 19:01:29.480: E/AndroidRuntime(17106):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
07-21 19:01:29.480: E/AndroidRuntime(17106):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
07-21 19:01:29.480: E/AndroidRuntime(17106):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
07-21 19:01:29.551: E/CursorWindow(17106): Could not allocate CursorWindow '/data/data/com.xoaquin.r07d/databases/ParseOfflineStore' of size 2097152 due to error -12.
07-21 19:01:38.119: E/WindowManager(674): Starting window AppWindowToken{4312f298 token=Token{42bd2558 ActivityRecord{42538230 u0 com.xoaquin.r07d/.MainActivity t57}}} timed out
```

**Below is the error that I got when I was using my own sqlite implementation, before changing to the Parse Local Datastore:**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.xoaquin.r07d.DefaultApplication: android.database.CursorWindowAllocationException: Cursor window allocation of 2048 kb failed. # Open Cursors=762 (# cursors opened by this proc=762)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4428)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:139)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1270)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.database.CursorWindowAllocationException: Cursor window allocation of 2048 kb failed. # Open Cursors=762 (# cursors opened by this proc=762)
at android.database.CursorWindow.<init>(CursorWindow.java:104)
at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.clearOrCreateWindow(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:198)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:139)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:133)
at com.parse.ParseSQLiteDatabase$12.then(ParseSQLiteDatabase.java:214)
at com.parse.ParseSQLiteDatabase$12.then(ParseSQLiteDatabase.java:205)
at com.parse.Task$11.run(Task.java:481)
at com.parse.Task$ImmediateExecutor.execute(Task.java:673)
at com.parse.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:477)
at com.parse.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:353)
at com.parse.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:364)
at com.parse.Task$9.then(Task.java:410)
at com.parse.Task$9.then(Task.java:402)
at com.parse.Task$11.run(Task.java:481)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

**Below the code for my application class which *is the only class of my own code* that is mentioned in the errors(maybe there's something different that is wrong in there):**

```
public class DefaultApplication extends Application{ 


    private static Context context; 

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        String manufacturer = Build.MANUFACTURER;
        String brand        = Build.BRAND;
        String product      = Build.PRODUCT;
        String model        = Build.MODEL;

        Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
        Parse.initialize(this, "KfBj6ivkLAaYqo", "ePZ6T7RmvGGw3"); 




            PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, MainActivity.class);

            ParseFacebookUtils.initialize("75589");

            PushService.subscribe(this, "todos", MainActivity.class);

            ParseUser cu = ParseUser.getCurrentUser(); 
            if(cu!=null){

            String nombretablausuario=cu.getUsername();  

            if(nombretablausuario!=null){

                if (nombretablausuario.contains("\\.")||nombretablausuario.contains("@")){
                          nombretablausuario=nombretablausuario.replaceAll("\\.", "");
                          nombretablausuario=nombretablausuario.replaceAll("@", "");    
                      }
            PushService.subscribe(this, nombretablausuario,MainActivity.class); 

            }

            ParseInstallation installation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
            installation.put("actualuser",cu.getUsername());
            installation.put("manufacturer", manufacturer);
            installation.put("brand", brand);
            installation.put("product", product);
            installation.put("model", model);
            installation.saveEventually();

            }

            String locale = getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getDisplayName();

            if(locale.contains("espa\u00F1ol")){ 

                PushService.subscribe(this, "jalert", JalertActivity.class);
                PushService.unsubscribe(this, "jalerting");
            }else{
                PushService.subscribe(this, "jalerting", JalertActivity.class);
                PushService.unsubscribe(this, "jalert");
            }

             context=getApplicationContext();

    }


    public static Context getCustomAppContext(){ 
      return context;
    }


}
```

Comment: This looks like a bug in parse.

Comment: @CL. Maybe... but remember I used my own sqlite implementation before, and the same type of error was present, it appeared after some time of testing various solutions, couldn't fix it, so that's the reason I changed to using the Parse DataStore. And still here...  with some new references that it has now to do with the Parse local databases..Any suggestion very much appreciated, I'd like to give it one more chance before going to query the network, online usage only though....

Comment: You should track down why you have 582 open cursors.

Comment: How?, I don't use cursors in my code, everything is done through Parse Local Datastore classes...

Comment: Ok, just checked and there's nothing in Parse's documentation about closing cursors or instances of the Local DataStore.... blank again...  @Code-Apprentice

Comment: I'm thinking it has to do with what user @danrah reported in one of his questions... This is because of querying within a service, it's true for instance that I've never had this problem while querying any db from an activity..  The thing is that a widget of this kind works with a service and associated classes... so,there's no way of doing this within an activity. Awaiting a genius or someone from Parse that can help me close cursors...

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer my own question to this: There's no solution at sight, no response from Parse team neither.

I am now using **SharedPreferences** file to handle local data to feed the widget. Any use of Parse Local Datastore will yield into cursor errors over time.

Hope this help someone experiencing the same problem while querying local sqlite databases from homescreen widgets and/or services.

Comment: Hey Carlos, Did parse ever respond to this? I'm seeing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a lot of Cursors open (582 of them) that that may not be needed. If you are explicitly creating Cursors, check that you also close them when they are no longer needed.

Comment: I don't use cursors in my code, everything is done through Parse Local Datastore classes...

Comment: I'm not a parse users but don't you need to somehow close their local datastore as well ?

Comment: I haven't seen it..  going to look for something like that in Parse's documentation in case I missed it.