# Closing all cursors associated with sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite, parse-platform

Is there a way of closing all cursors that have been used to query a certain database?

I Don´t have the variable names, need a "close.all" sort of code.

Suppose you have some of these cursors, managed by external libraries (Parse Offline DataStore), not by your own code:

```
Cursor cursorvariablenames = database.rawQuery
("SELECT " + NAME + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + DAY_PERIOD[day_counter * 2]
+ " = '" + day + "' AND " + DAY_PERIOD[day_counter * 2 + 1] + " = "
+ Integer.toString(period), null);
```

I know the name of the sqlite DB = (ParseOfflineStore), and would like to close all cursors that are used by or point toward this DB.

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer my own question to this: There's no solution at sight, no response from Parse team neither.

I am now using **SharedPreferences** file to handle local data to feed the widget. Any use of Parse Local Datastore will yield into cursor errors over time.

Hope this help someone experiencing the same problem while querying local sqlite databases from homescreen widgets and/or services.

Answer (score 0):

You may try closing your DB with[`db.close();`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteClosable.html#close()) or [`dbHelper.close();`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#close()), then all cursors operating on that database should be closed.

Comment: Ok, how should I define the db variable for db.close();? remember I´m not managing it directly..  the parse library is..

Comment: @CarlosAndresTorrenegraE if you mean [this library](https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#localdatastore) by Parse, then it will manage closing and opening the DB automatically. You don't have to worry about such operations, I believe.

Comment: That´s the one, but I´m getting errors related to not closing cursors. So I wanted to try somehting... The thing is that I´m querying the local datastore from a class (widgetfactoryclass), this is related to a homescreen widget and its underlying service. Never got this type of error querying local db´s from activities, but from doing this I get them, no answer so far.. [Look at this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24877247/how-to-fix-android-database-cursorwindowallocationexception-crash)

Comment: @CarlosAndresTorrenegraE why don't you try using ParseObject (following the Android [guideline](https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#localdatastore)) instead of ParseInstallation? Plus, update the Parse SDK if it's been long since your last update.

Comment: @CarlosAndresTorrenegraE Also use ParseQuery<ParseObject> instead of `database.rawQuery`.
In short, refactor your code following their simple API guide.